# What happens when a wormhole mouth moves over a smaller object?

Tags: general-relativity, thought-experiment, wormholes

This is really lots of questions in one, but I'll start by expanding on the title. Say that we have an infinite, euclidian universe (4d spacetime) with nothing in it but a single object (1m diameter solid sphere). Now, I magically deform this space to have a single (worm)hole whose mouths (2m diameter) are colinear with the object:

```
O O  *
```

For simplicity's sake, these wormholes are the kind that do not gravitate. If we assume that the mouths of a wormhole can move relatively to each other, there's nothing stopping me from giving the right mouth a push towards the object, and letting it pass over it:

```
O O->*
```

Any kind of intuition tells you that the object comes out of the left mouth with the same speed the right mouth passed over it with:

```
<-* O O->
```

If all you can see are the object and the wormhole, then from all points of view the object accellerated. From that perspective, if I bring the right mouth back to rest with the left one, the object keeps on moving at the same speed:

```
<-* O O
```

However, things get interesting when you consider *why* that object moved. No impulse was applied to it, nor was there a change of reference frame. That object moved because the space around it was moved through the wormhole. From that perspective, when I stop the right mouth, there is no reason for the object to keep going - it wasn't moving in the first place:

```
* O O
```

But now, something even stranger happens. If I take that resultant configuration and push the right mouth again, the object, and all space colinear with it, is moved *again*:

```
<-* O O->
```

If we actually created a wormhole between two solar systems in our galaxy, the mouths would have to be moving at different speeds for it to be practical. If the target solar system were closer or further from the galactic center, the difference would be very noticeable, and the rate of spatial tearing and displacement needed to keep the two wormholes inside their solar systems would no doubt require a collossal amount of energy.

My question(s) is this: Is what I said true? Would what I described happen how I described it? Are there any other factors I haven't considered?